# Outlook PST export fails because of custom form errors?

Tags: vbscript, outlook, exchange-server, pst

I am trying to export a user's calendar from Outlook 2007 to a PST file.

The calendar contains appointment items making use of an obsolete custom form (written in VBS).

This form attempts to retrieve data from a database server that no longer exists, which results in error messages appearing during the export. Eventually, the export hangs and does not complete.

What options do I have as far as methods to work around this problem?

Skipping the appointment items with this error would be acceptable, as long as the balance of non-erroneous appointment items can be exported.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Filter out appointments with the custom message class by only specifying the standard IPM.Appointment class:

```
    RestrictedItems = MAPIFolder.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Appointment' ")
```

2. Or avoid using the Outlook Object Model by using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language).